# Can't access locals in external javascript

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am developing sails.js app in which I want to access locals in external javascript file. I am returning data in response in form of `{error: "username"}` and I can access it easily by calling `<%= error %>` inside my view. But I have another external javascript file and inside it I want to do `console.log(error)` but it is always undefined. I have also tried it the other way by declaring function inside external javascript like this `function notifyError(error){console.log(error)}` but when I try to call this function from my view it says that this function is undefined.

Any idea on how I can connect my view with external javascript file? I want this because I am using PNotify and it always says that this is undefined even that I have improted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, you're not understanding how views, server side rendering and EJS works! When you code `<%= error %>` you're not "declaring a variable". You are saying this: "Replace `<%= error %>` with its content". So the HTML file that you're providing, instead of a static string like "my error here", you can change that programmatically. This is what happens:

```
Sails app / Server side:
("view.ejs")
<div>
    <%= error %>
</div>

("anyController.js")
res.render('view.ejs', {error : "my error string"});

User side:
<div>
    my error string
</div>
```

Take a look at the docs [HERE](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/views/locals).

EDIT: Also if you want to change anything in the view, you can use an external js file and provide it to the client (simple script tag). A lib like Angular, VueJS, etc. should be enough. Those libs can make get/post requests to your Sails app, that should provide json answers. Again, take a good look at the docs!

Comment: Hmm after a bit of digging I understand it better now. I have used <%= error %> inside my function call so it is like alert("<%=error%>"); and it is working now. If you do a little edit to adapt your answer on using inside javascript and not only plain html I will accept it

Comment: EJS and server side rendering should be used to dynamically change content but serve it once as a static HTML file. Therefore it should be used to render one page differently given the arguments provided, so you write a "profile.ejs" page that can be used for any profile with its content changing when your arguments change. So what are you trying to accomplish, if I understood it correctly, is not very good practice. BUT you can do it with a <script> tag like this: <script> myvar = <%= error %> </script> .